# How to override submit button event in add/edit dialog in jqGrid

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid for a scheduling process. In the grid, I am displaying the working hours and other details of employees under a department. On clicking a row in the grid, another grid has to pop-up which gives details of the corresponding row in the master grid. For example you can refer to http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html (adanced>masterdetails). This shows an example of two grids where on clicking a row in the master grid you get the invoice details in the below grid. I too need the same functionality and added to it, I have to add/edit the rows in the second grid. Both the grid datatype are local. On clicking submit button in the add/edit dialog I want to override the default action which submits the data to the server, and write my own function. The function is to store the added details/edited details into an object and bind it as a data block to a div.

I tried `onclickSubmit`, but it was still invoking the default method.
Added to this, i would like to reload the grid with the new row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for your first problem, what you can do...onSelectRow property of jqgrid you can send the data of that row as local data and load a new grid just below to previous grid

for example, this you can write with first grid

```
onSelectRow: function(){
var sel_id = jQuery("#grid").jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selrow');
```

//this will give you id of the selected row

now to get values of the column for this row, there are several methods

i'll go with this one, lets say i have date as a column in this row

so,

```
var date=getCellValue(sel_id,'date');
```

and now you can load a new grid in this same function and send this data to that grid

and now your second problem, for the custom functionality of add/edit dialogue you can make use of this event and over ride it

beforeSubmit

check this

```
http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:form_editing#editgridrow
```

Comment: i tired it..but beforeSubmit is still nvoking the server call which has to be blocked. is there any way to do it

Comment: so you dont want your data to go to the server?

Comment: you can send the data to server and bind the data in server itself, return object from server and then bind data to div in view.???

Comment: or you can write ur own code by over riding the click event of that submit button..

Comment: no..i dont want to go to the server as of now. the reason is i will be editing rows in the second grid,which updates the first grid with the new values. Similarly i will be editing most of the rows in the first row, and then by an click event of a button i will be sending all the edited data to the server. This is the functionality i am trying to implement. but cant make it out :(

Comment: can i know how to override that submit button in the dialog of edit/add

Comment: do u really want to have two grids for this reason? you can a have a grid with edit button with each row and then you can have a submit button which will pick the data from all the edited rwos and post it to the server

Comment: yes piyush,i want it. the reason is the first grid gives the summary and the second gives the details of each row. the second grid gets refreshed when a new row is selected in first grid. the case is similar to the master detail example in http://trirand.com/blog/jqgrid/jqgrid.html this page.